# About the determinant of a symmetric matrix with even diagonal

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus, bilinear-form, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $A$,$B$   two integer, symmetric, $n\times n$ matrix with even diagonal. We suppose also that $A$ has odd determinant (so $n$ is even).

Even discarding the hypothesis of even diagonal for $A$ it's not difficult to show that:

$$\det(A)\equiv\det(A+2B)\pmod4$$

But I suspect that if $A$ is even diagonal too then we have the stronger equivalence:
$$\det(A)\equiv\det(A+2B)\pmod8$$

How could I prove it?

Comment: First suggestion: It suffices to prove this when $B$ has the form $E_{i,j} + E_{j,i}$ or the form $2E_{i,i}$ (since every symmetric matrix with even diagonal is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of matrices of this form).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I have used this method for the modulo 4 congruence, but I can not adapt it for the modulo 8 congruence

Comment: You have reduced it to something like "$\det U \equiv \det V \mod 2$, where $U$ is the result of removing rows $i$ and $j$ and columns $i$ and $j$ from $A$, and where $V$ is the result of removing row $i$ and column $j$ from $A$", right? Because if you have, there is a rather neat proof of this using Dodgson's condensation formula (hint: $x^2 \equiv x \mod 2$ and $\det A \equiv 1 \mod 2$).

Comment: (The reduction relies on the fact that $\det\left(A + 2\left(E_{i, j} + E_{j, i}\right)\right) = \det A + 4 \det U - 4 \det V$, where of course the $4 \det U$ is really the sum of two terms that happen to be equal because $A$ is symmetric.)

Comment: Also, when I say "Dodgson's condensation formula", I mean the formula $\det A \cdot \det U = \det \left(A_{\sim i, \sim i}\right) \det \left(A_{\sim j, \sim j}\right) - \det \left(A_{\sim i, \sim j}\right) \det \left(A_{\sim j, \sim i}\right)$, where $A_{\sim x, \sim y}$ means the submatrix of $A$ obtained by removing row $x$ and column $y$. In our case, $\det \left(A_{\sim i, \sim i}\right)$ and $\det \left(A_{\sim j, \sim j}\right)$ are even and thus can be neglected, whereas the matrices $A_{\sim i, \sim j}$ and $A_{\sim j, \sim i}$ are each other's transposes and thus have equal $\det$s.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thanks, it works!